# Object localization down to the pixel

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, detection, localization

I am somewhat confused on the terminology used in Computer Vision. Suppose I wanted to detect (localize) an object (say, a human) in an image. However, a box around the human is not sufficient, what I need is a pixelwise localization. More precisely, I need a mask telling me which pixels belong to the human and which ones don't. 
If I wanted to find papers dealing with this problem, what would be the term to search for?

- Object detection: Yes, but most approaches actually work in terms of bounding boxes
- Object localization: If I see it correctly, this is essentially used as a synonym for object detection
- Image segmentation: Here we segment objects in terms of pixels but we do not necessarily only aim to segment out one specific object that is known.

Is there very famous work in this area I should not miss?

Comment: "what I need is a pixelwise localization" For what?

Comment: How is a box not "pixelwise"? A location is a *single point*.

Comment: detection != localization (at least in English as I understand it)

Comment: Define very precisely what you *actually* need; that might be hard, maybe start with an actual example of an image as input, and an actual representation of the output you want.

Comment: You need to look for "Human Pose Estimation" and of course Segmentation (if all you need is the pixels belonging to the human).

Comment: @endolith: Example: calculate average color of the object.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: How would you define localization then? Any sources? I think it is  pretty obvious what I need. I need a mask telling me which pixels belong to the object and which ones don't. I edited my question.

Comment: @TolgaBirdal: True, that's another term going into this direction. But these methods might only give me the location of the body joints. So it is not precisely what I want :)

Comment: @user1809923: obviously, it is **not** obvious what you want. That's the whole point of this comment discussion...

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Obviously at least not for you, without meaning to be rude. As you are talking in the present I assume that it is still not clear? I have found a very interesting paper called "Simultaneous Detection and Segmentation", it talks quite extensively about the problem I am describing. They probably do a better job in explaining what I mean than me. As a side note, Jonathan Long seems to call it "pixelwise prediction" in his paper "Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation", haven't read that paper yet though. Admittedly, A better term than "pixelwise localization".

Comment: "More precisely, I need a mask telling me which pixels belong to the human and which ones don't."  I believe that's called "segmentation", not "localization".  Localization would be finding a single coordinate for the "center" of the person and not caring what the size or edges are.

Comment: @endolith: if that is the definition of localization, you are right. However, I do not think that "image segmentation" very precisely describes the given task, since we want to segment ONE KNOWN object. Maybe "simultaneous detection and segmentation" or "pixelwise prediction" is the closest there is.